# remains in custody on a $1 million bail

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I'm wondering what "on" means in the following. I understand "released on bail" and "out on bail," where "on" indicates the means whereby the release is granted. But the meaning doesn't fit in the following sentence:

> Gadlin remains in custody **on** a $1 million bail, court records show. CNN reached out to his public defender for comment but has not yet received a response.

https://lite.cnn.com/en/article/h_9d5daceb79dc9aba36f09575485c048e

Answer (score 3):

This means that the arraigning judge has set bail at $1MM, and Gadlin (or his agent) has either declined to post it, or cannot raise the amount. He therefore has not been released.

*eta: Newswriting often takes shortcuts that would not normally be used in formal writing or general speech. In this case, using "in custody on a $1MM bail" is newswriting shorthand for what might be more formally written as "in custody having not posted bail set at $1MM". It could also have been written as "in custody on [the basis of not having posted] a $1MM bail", including the words in brackets, but newswriting assumes space is at a premium, and assumes a level of understanding that may not be appropriate for new speakers of English.*

Comment: Do you find the usage natural?

Comment: I don't generally consider newswriting "natural"; I don't find it _unnatural_.

Comment: @Apollyon I found it natural, but I believe "remains in custody **with** a $1 million bail." is just as good and may make more sense for learning purposes.

Comment: I think you can probably say that "on bail" is idiomatic. Every AmE and BrE speaker knows what it means, On the other hand I've never heard "with bail".

Comment: @PeterJennings The phrase "on bail" itself is fine; the issue is its compatibility with "remains in custody." One could say "A person was released on bail" meaning the person was released on condition that he will return for trial, or his bail will be forfeited. But it's odd to say a person remains in custody on bail in the sense that he remains in custody on condition that he will return, or his bail will be forfeited.

Answer (score 0):

"On bail" is idiomatic and can be found in dictionaries (in some cases in the context of the expression "remand on bail").